# R: Insert a column at a specific place in R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have following data table

```
      user_id user_system_days event total_pics 
[1,] 21196680             0     0         124   
[2,] 21197699             0     0           4   
[3,] 21197861             0     0          14   
[4,] 21198820             1     0          21   
[5,] 21199601             0     0           3   
[6,] 21203847             0     0           1
```

Based on a value in column event I want to insert a column to the data table, My approach was by writing a function, and use that function to return a value.

```
opposite_event  <- function(x) {
  y <- 1
  if (x == 1) 
    y <- 0
  return (y)
}
```

I called function as follows:

```
dt[,op_event:=opposite_event(dt$event)]
```

This actually added the column but values were wrong:

```
      user_id user_system_days event total_pics op_event
[1,] 21196680             0     0         124      0
[2,] 21197699             0     0           4      0
[3,] 21197861             0     0          14      0
[4,] 21198820             1     0          21      0
[5,] 21199601             0     0           3      0
[6,] 21203847             0     0           1      0
```

Based on my function if value of the `dt$event` is `1` then return value should be `0` and if `dt$event` is 0 then return value should `1` Plus I wasn't sure how to insert the column into a specific location like right after event column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is not vectorized, Replace it with `y <- ifelse(x == 0, 1, 0)`.

You don't really need a custom function in my opinion:

```
dt[,op_event := ifelse(event == 0, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: should work such that if event == 1 then value of op_event is 1 and if event == 0 then op_event should be 1

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis yup.

Comment: @SeñorO whats the best way to re-arrange the column order such as getting the column op_event after event column?

Comment: You must do that after you create the column. The default way is just to list the names in order with data.table. You can also use numbers if you include `with=FALSE`. So like `dt[,list(uder_id, user_system_days....)]` or `dt[,list(1, 2, 3, 5, 4), with=FALSE]`

Comment: the idiomatic way to rearrange columns is to use `setcolorder`. That'll rearrange by reference (no copies). Doing `dt[, list(.)]` is a column subset which'll create a copy.

Comment: Update on another way: `dt[, op_event := as.integer(!event)]`